# Chrome browser is not starting on jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Previously all my automation testcases working fine on jenkins using chromedriver version 73. After that client updated jenkins (version 2.346.3) and related plugins. All my testcases started failing. I thought it was because of Chromedriver and chrome browser mismatch issue. So I updated Chromedriver to the version 105.0.5195.52 but it is still failing on same point. Chrome browser version on linux is 105.

Error on console log

[image]

chrome browser version

[image]

Comment: It is showing a successfully launched chrome driver. So please your test cases fail error details.

Comment: @arpita biswas Here you can check console log and code i have for starting chrome browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73775932/chrome-browser-not-starting-on-jenkins-in-headless-mode-on-linux